# Make Emojis return a length of 1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, emoji

I'm working on an operational-transformation library in JavaScript. I'm running into an issue where testing the `.length` property on an Emoji returns 2 or 3. (fun experiment! Run `[...'‍‍']` in your Node REPL).

That wouldn't be an issue, except for the fact that the server portion of the library reads emojis as having a length of 1, no matter the Emoji.

What I'm looking to do is make the JS return Emojis as having a length of 1.  Is there anything out there like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, *natively*, you cannot.

There are modules to workaround this problem, such as [`stringz`](https://github.com/sallar/stringz) or [`string-length`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/string-length) (which seems to be buggy):

```
const stringLength = require("stringz");

''.length;
//=> 2

stringLength('');
//=> 1

stringLength('‍‍');
//=> 1
```

However, you couldn't modify the the length of these characters, because that's how they are built.

Comment: However, `stringLength('‍‍')` is 5, because it's a composed character (MAN+ZWJ+WOMAN+ZWJ+GIRL). Whether this is "correct" is a complicated question.

Comment: @duskwuff Oh, correct. I found another one: `stringz` which seems to work.